# Why should events in C# take (sender, EventArgs)?

Tags: c#, .net, events

It's known that you should declare events that take as parameters `(object sender, EventArgs args)`. Why?

Comment: it provides you with a clear, "return to sender" type message, you know where it came from, and you have the messsage itself, at the time you need to do something, even if you have a custom event args, it should derive from system.eventargs

Comment: if you just pass in, your object, you are coupling the handler and the caller, and its just unnecessary, just create a stub object that is a decorator for your object, thats just for events, and make this object live, close to the event, not its cake.

Comment: I 2nd this question. All these people are saying it's "flexible" and "consistent"... but this pattern forces you to cast the event args every time you use it... what if you're handler only accepts one type of sender? What happens when someone sends the wrong type because you've made it so generalized? Does it crash? Are you supposed to do error handling, to handle all the crap you didn't want in the first place? I don't get it. If you give it the proper signature in the first place, then people can at least know what to expect!

Comment: In my opinion, the whole event system in C# is crap.  It should be more like what CAB provides for you: ability to publish/subscribe to events, without the need to couple your classes to one-another or create a new class for every type of event-arg.  Because of the terrible event-system in C# now, using events requires a ridiculous amount of boiler-plate, especially with CAB :(

Comment: Is there anything *wrong* with events accepting the actual type of the sender (or a common base type), and the actual type of the arguments (or a common base type)? I'd rather break this convention than follow it, if I had all the cards on the table and knew the implications. It feels out-dated somehow.

Comment: @Mark I don't see the need to cast the event args, unless your method handles multiple events that each have a different type for the event args.

Comment: @Stijn: Huh? Even if the method only accepts *one* type of event, you'd still have to cast it because your signature uses some generic EventArgs rather than the actual args you wanted.

Comment: @Mark see http://pastebin.com/dQwbyTu5 for an example. Custom type, no casting needed. And now I'm realising, you're probably talking about the exact signature `(object sender, EventArgs args)` and not just any signature that has a sender and args?

Comment: @Stijn: Yes, I was referring to the exact signature. But perhaps that's not what the OP meant, or what this pattern implies? What about for "sender" then, does that have to be `object` or can you use "a derived type" (i.e., anything)?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This allows the consuming developer the ability to write a single event handler for multiple events, regardless of sender or event.

**Edit:** Why would you need a different pattern?  You can inherit EventArgs to provide any amount of data, and changing the pattern is only going to serve to confuse and frustrate any developer that is forced to consume this new pattern.

Comment: I usually just pass whatever I need in the handler. If I need an event with no information, I declare it void. If I need to give the event 1 specific object, I pass that alone. It's not that I have a different pattern, I'm just not sure of the necessity of a pattern (outside framework code).

Comment: You pass what *you* need, but that's needlessly inflexible, and breaking an established best-practice without any gain in function.

Comment: The need to derive from EventArgs is causing me a problem. The class that I want to use as TEventArgs is a DataContract and I cannot inherit from EventArgs in that case because EventArgs doesn't have a DataContract. Great pattern!

Comment: So create a DCEventArgs class that inherits from EventArgs and has a dependency on your custom DC class.

Comment: I wrote a class a while back for testing purposes that sinks a handler on every event on an object, and logs those events. However, it requires that all handlers take the (object sender, EventArgs e) signature, otherwise logging the parameters to the handler would be a LOT harder.

Comment: @wizlb Didn't you *ever* inherit a class? Because it looked like so.

Answer (score 14):

Actually this is debatable whether or not this is the best practice way to do events. There is the school of thought that as events are intended to decouple two segments of code, the fact that the event handler gets the sender, and has to know what type to cast the sender into in order to do anything with it is an anti-pattern.

Comment: Events are not intended to decouple anything. They are intended to provide notification and **nothing more**. From MSDN - _"Events enable a class or object to notify other classes or objects when something of interest occurs"_

Comment: It's noted that casting the sender object increases coupling on something that isn't statically checked.  This can be done safer by moving the requirements of a sender to the eventArgs.

Comment: Events *are* intended for decoupling for anyone who uses them that way. And decoupling is often a good idea. Don't let narrow interpretation of guidelines make your code worse.

Answer (score 6):

Because it's a good pattern for any callback mechanism, regardless of language.  You want to know who sent the event (the sender) and data that is pertinent to the event (EventArgs).

Comment: Do I want to know who send it? Or do I want to know the message it has send to me? I think it depends on the situation.

Answer (score 6):

Using a single parameter, EventArgs, for the data passed by an event allows you to add data to your event in future versions of your software without breaking existing consumers.  You simply add new members to an existing EventArgs-derived class, or create a derived class with the new members.

Otherwise consistency and the principle of least surprise justify using EventArgs for passing data.

As for sender, in some (but not all) cases it's useful to know what type sent the event.  Using a type other than object for the sender argument is too restrictive: it would mean that other senders couldn't reuse the same event signature.

Answer (score 2):

It is a good pattern to use, that way what ever implements the event can find what was sending it.

Also overriding the EventArgs and passing data through them is the best method.  The EventArgs are a base class.  If you look at various controls that call events, they have overridden EventArgs which gives you more information about the event.

Even if you don't need the arguments to do the event, if you do not include them with the first run of the framework and want to add them later, you break all previous implementations, and have to re-write them.  Plus if you a creating a framework and going to distribute that it becomes worse because everybody that uses your framework will need to refactor.

Answer (score 2):

Chris Anderson says in the Framework Design Guidelines book:

> [T]his is just about a pattern.  By having event arguments packaged in a class you get better versioning semantics.  By having a common pattern `(sender, e)` it is easily learned as the signature for all events.

There are situations mostly involving interop that would require deviation from this pattern.

Comment: "Easily learned as the signature"... when working in C#, we usually have Visual Studio at our hands, which will readily tell you what the signature actually is. Why is this even a concern?

Comment: @Eran : I'm not sure what fryguybob meant, but if event data were passed as separate parameters and a new one is added, all existing code breaks.  But if a new property is added to an EventArgs-derived type, all the old code continues happily using the old properties and just ignores the new one.

Comment: @BenVoigt, if it's a needed feature in your application then that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

It seemed that this was Microsoft's way to evolve the event model over time. It also seems that they are also allowing another way to do it with the "new" Action delegate and it's variations.

Comment: How is Action an event? At best it can provide a callback not an event.

Comment: @Kugel `public event Action<bool, int, Blah> DiagnosticsEvent;` - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431359/event-action-vs-event-eventhandler

Comment: @ANeves you're 6 years late, but I believe the original answer was implying using Action **instead** of events.

Comment: @Kugel I don't see the same implication that you do, but I understand how you can read it that way. And, which "original answer"? This answer was never edited.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you would like to force all of your event consumers to use a particular event parameter, for example, a security event which passes a boolean parameter, true for good, false for bad.
In this case you want your consumer to be painfully aware of the new parameter, i.e. you want your consumers to be coupled with that parameter. Take note, your consumers are still decoupled from your event firing class, but not from your event.

I suspect that this scenario applies to a large number of cases and in those cases the value of EventArgs is greatly reduced.

Answer (score 0):

The **EventArgs** class alone is useless since it must be derived to instantiate with any content.  This would indicate a subclass should be used, and many already exist in .NET.  Sadly, I can't find any good generic ones.

Let's say you want to delegate logging to a generic event... WITHOUT WRITING YOUR OWN EventArgs SUBCLASS.  It may seem a pointless exercise, but I like using existing features.  You can pass your string through the Object argument, but that goes against it's intended use.  Try to find a good reference of EventArgs subclasses on Google, and you'll come up dry.  (At least I did.)

ReSharper helps a bit, since when you type "EventArgs" you'll see a list of all classes (within your using/imports scope) that CONTAIN the string "EventArgs".  Perusing the list you'll see many classes with no string members.  When you get to **ControlEventArgs**, you see that the Text property might be used, but with all of the overhead of a windows control.  **ConvertEventArgs** might be useful, since you pass the type along with the data, but this still requires tight coupling that's neither well-documented nor inherently type-safe.  **DataReceivedEventArgs** has no implementation.  **EntryWrittenEventArgs** requires an EventLogEntry with a byte array or StreamingContext for data.  **ErrorEventArgs** is closer, with an Exception message, if you don't mind calling all of your log events Exception ErrorEvents internally.  **FileSystemEventArgs** is probably the closest yet, with two strings and a required WatcherChangeTypes enum argument that CAN be set to 0, if you know what you're doing.  **LabelEditEventArgs** uses an int and a string, if you don't mind requiring the Windows.Forms namespace.  **RenamedEventArgs** is similar to FileSystemEventArgs with an extra string.  Finally, **ResolveEventArgs** in System.Runtime.InteropServices passes a single string.  There are other libraries, but I stuck to some of the most common ones.  So, depending on the implementation I can use **ErrorEventArgs**, **FileSystemEventArgs** or **ResolveEventArgs** for logging.

Comment: For what it's worth, If you simply need to pass single values you can write a generic public class SingleEventArgs<T> : System.EventArgs { public T Value; } and a corresponding generic event handler delegate.

Answer (score 0):

"Object sender" allows to reuse one method for multiple objects when the handler method is supposed to do something with the object that raised the event, for example 3 textbox can have one single handler that will reset the text of the firing textbox.

EventArgs's main advantage is that it allows to refactor event information without the need to change signatures of all handlers in all projects that are subscribed to this kind of event.

I can't think of a smarter way to deal with events.

Comment: If the event only works on textboxes in your example, why not declare the "sender" as a `TextBox` rather than a generic object? Now you have to cast the sender to a `TextBox` inside the function instead, and if it isn't actually a `TextBox` because someone mistakenly sent you the wrong object because your signature wasn't clear that it only works on textboxes...your program will likely crash. This is what I don't get.