# Declaring Control in XAML Without Adding It to Visual Tree

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I want to create `Control` in Xaml, I can however create this `Control` using C# code, but somehow it's too verbose.

So I declare this `Control` in `Page.Resources` with `x:Name="UserControl"`.

On runtime I will attach this `UserControl` to the `Grid`.

**Page.xaml :**

```
<Page Loaded="OnLoaded">
   <Page.Resources>
      <UserControl x:Name="UserControl">
                <TextBlock>Hi, There</TextBlock>
      </UserControl>
   </Page.Resources>
   <Grid x:Name="Grid">
   </Grid>
</Page>
```

**Page.xaml.cs**

```
private void OnLoaded(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   Grid.Children.Add(UserControl); // exception
}
```

When running this, I got `COMException` with message: `WinRT information: Element is already the child of another element`.

I check property `Parent` in `UserControl` is null, how can this exception happen ?

How to declare Control in XAML without adding it to Visual Tree ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this by creating `DependencyProperty`,

```
public class MyPage : Page
{
      public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderTemplateProperty =
         DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(HeaderTemplate), 
         typeof(UIElement), typeof(MyPage), new PropertyMetadata(null));

      public UIElement HeaderTemplate
      {
          get
          {
              return (UIElement)GetValue(HeaderTemplateProperty);
          }
          set
          {
              SetValue(HeaderTemplateProperty, value);
          }
      }
}
```

Then I can add any `UIElement`, without adding it `VisualTree`.

```
<Page Loaded="OnLoaded">
   <Page.HeaderTemplate>
      <UserControl x:Name="UserControl">
         <TextBlock>Hi, There</TextBlock>
      </UserControl>
   </Page.HeaderTemplate>
   <Grid x:Name="Grid">
   </Grid>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a re-usable control in XAML, add a `UserControl` to your project.

[image: UserControl]

Next, add whatever has to be in your control in this new file:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="App13.MyUserControl1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">

    <TextBlock>Hi, There</TextBlock>
</UserControl>
```

Now you can use this control any amount of times either in XAML on your page

```
<Page
    x:Class="App13.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App13"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <StackPanel  x:Name="MyStackPanel">
            <!-- Stack the control 4 times -->
            <local:MyUserControl1 />
            <local:MyUserControl1 />
            <local:MyUserControl1 />
            <local:MyUserControl1 />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Or in code behind, note that you'll have to create a new object here.

```
// add 2 more
MyStackPanel.Children.Add(new MyUserControl1());
MyStackPanel.Children.Add(new MyUserControl1());
```

A user control is a separate entity from your page. If you want to use events, check [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13447940/how-to-create-user-define-new-event-for-user-control-in-wpf-one-small-example) (works the same as in WPF). If you want to add custom properties, read up on [Dependency Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/custom-dependency-properties).

---

Edit: If you don't want control re-usability and just want to declare a control on your page, do it inside the Grid instead of Page.Resources. Then there's no need to try and create it in code behind.

```
<Page>
   <Page.Resources>
   </Page.Resources>
   <Grid x:Name="Grid">
      <TextBlock>Hi, There</TextBlock>
   </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: Nice, but if I use `event`, I must wrap this `event` in `UserControl` too.

Comment: Thanks, I do know how to create and use UserControl, but that doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Well it's either the usercontrol approach or the 2nd part of my reply.