# How to allow assigning an event handler in XAML to a button inside a UserControl?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have a `UserControl` **UC1** which contains a `Button` **B1**.

I'm using that `UserControl` (**UC1**) inside another `UserControl` **UC0**, and I want to subscribe to the button's `Click` in **UC0**'s XAML.

[image: User Control]

What I want in **UC0**'s XAML:

```
<y:UC1 ClickOnButtonB1="Click1"/>
```

How do I get that?

(Both `UserControl`s are mine. I can edit **UC1**'s properties. I just couldn't find a way to add a property in **UC1** that allows **UC0** to assign an event handler in XAML.)

Comment: This answer might be for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66991746/1136211

Comment: It is best (and most typically for WPF) to declare a static RoutedCommand instance in the UserControl.
Indicate this instance in the button.
And at any top level, you can "catch" this command and set handlers for it.
This technique is used in many default implementations.

Comment: @EldHasp I don't understand. What exactly do you mean?

Comment: The topic is closed and I cannot give an answer with an example code.
Do you know how to work with RoutedCommand?
Create your own instances, "catch" the called RoutedCommand and set handlers to it (CommandBindings)?