# Signature of .NET Events

Tags: .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why should events in C# take (sender, EventArgs)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104674/why-should-events-in-c-sharp-take-sender-eventargs)

I just ran the VS2012 Code Analysis tool on a project and found that it complains about this snippet:

```
public delegate void PerMbHandler(long totalMb);

public event PerMbHandler NotifyMegabyteIncrement;
```

> CA1009 Declare the second parameter of 'MyWebClient.PerMbHandler' as an EventArgs, or an instance of a type that extends EventArgs, named 'e'.

[MSDN explains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28CA1009%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version=v4.5%29;k%28DevLang-csharp%29&rd=true):

> Event handler methods take two parameters. The first is of type System.Object and is named 'sender'. This is the object that raised the event. The second parameter is of type System.EventArgs and is named 'e'. This is the data that is associated with the event. For example, if the event is raised whenever a file is opened, the event data typically contains the name of the file.

MSDN states simply what the convention is, not the reason it exists.

What can go wrong using a *long* parameter rather than a subclass of *EventArgs*?  Is it a matter of convention and programmer expectations, or is there some subtle technical reason that the pattern must be followed?  I say subtle, because the code seems to work fine.

Comment: I don't think its a matter of it not working, it just goes against the covnention for event handlers. I think most developers will expect an event handler to have something of the form described in MSDN, and will look at your delegate just a bit askance - particularly if they're expecting to be able to get a reference to the sender when the event is raised, but the handler for the event doesn't support the signature to provide it.

Comment: @DavidW: You may well be right and that was my first thought.  I'll be interested to see if there are perhaps edge cases where things really do break.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What can go wrong using a long parameter rather than a subclass of
>   EventArgs?

**Event Args**
It's not wrong per se but it's not extensible. For sake of argument, perhaps in 6 months you need to pass two longs, or add a string, or add a whole list of information. With `EventArgs` in the signature, you can pass any derived type and not break existing consumers; with a specific value type, you are very limited.

EventArgs also allows you to communicate with the class that raised the event, e.g. `CancelEventArgs`.

**Sender**
Honestly, I rarely use sender for anything. It can also be somewhat ambiguous. For example, a custom event on a control triggered by input into a textbox...who is the sender? the textbox (probably more useful), or the control which declares the custom event?

Still, it is a familiar convention, and with a well-documented interface it can be useful.

Comment: sender is useful when you have the same event handler code attached to many different items.

Comment: That's a good example...which I guess was the point of my answer: the `(sender, args)` signature supports a wide variety of possibilities, even if you don't need them today.

Comment: Just to confirm. Can you really not pass a subclass to a delegate? How does that not violate polymorphism? What's the logic behind that?

Comment: No, you can pass subclasses to delegates. It's been a while since I wrote this, but I believe my point was that if the event signature only took primitives (see the OP), you would be limited if you wanted to pass additional values in the future. By passing `EventArgs` (or a subclass thereof) you can preserve signatures even if the input data changes.

Comment: So... if you were to add additional parameters, it saves you from having to alter all of the target function signatures? Is that the only advantage?

Comment: That, and consistency with all event signatures.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing can go wrong, event and event handler signatures are strongly typed-checked.  All the message does is warn you about the speed-bump this gives another programmer that uses your event, being puzzled why the event has such an unusual signature.  Speed bumps beget bugs, the kind produced by the programmer insisting he needs to get the *sender* for example.

Keep in mind what the FxCop (aka "Code Analysis") tries to do.  It doesn't check for errors, that's the job of the compiler.  It is there to let you know about things you might not have thought of.  It can be a bit naggy at times because of that, particularly when it noodles about CAS or flags the notorious CA2000 inappropriately.  But this one is certainly a good warning, you didn't think of it.