# Why is sender not in EventArgs?

Tags: .net, events, event-handling

Why does the `sender` of an event warrant its own parameter? Why is it not just a property of the `EventArgs` class?

Comment: It allows events to be chained more easily, I suppose. You can send the same `EventArgs` with a different `sender` without having to create a new object..

Comment: It's a design decision by the C# developers. Isn't that like asking why Java developers decided to use `eventArgs.getSource()` instead of using an `Object source` argument?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why should events in C# take (sender, EventArgs)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104674/why-should-events-in-c-sharp-take-sender-eventargs)

Comment: That's a valid question. But I think `sender` is catered to what object was sending an event, that is, is it a `Button`, a `Textbox` etc. While `EventArgs` caters what kind of event was being triggered, is it from the `Mouse`, `Keyboard` or even the `System` itself.